# .$save not working in angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Factory

```
app.factory('Shipment', function($resource) {
  return function(auth_token){
    return $resource(basePath + "shipments/:id", { id: '@_id' }, {
      query:       { method: 'GET', params: {auth_token: auth_token}, isArray:true                                  },
      update:      { method: 'PUT'                                                                                  }
    });
  }
});
```

Controller

```
$scope.shipment = new Shipment($scope.shipment)
$scope.shipment.$save(function() {
  debugger
});
```

It gives me this error:

`$scope.shipment.$save is not a function`

query and get are working fine.

Comment: Isn't $save supposed to go inside the calls for items e.g. your `get` method? You're calling it on the resource aren't you?

Comment: No, its not going. It is giving the error before the request initiate

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. `$scope.shipment` is a resource, `$save` is used on objects it returns, not on the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your factory like below.

```
do ->
  angular.module('yourModule').factory('prefixShipment', ['$resource', function($resource){
    $resource(basePath + "shipments/:id", { id: '@_id' }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    })
  }])
```

Now for saving use the below snippet.

```
shipment = new prefixShipment({shipment: shipment})
shipment.save({},function(response){
    //your code      
})
```

Forget record.

```
prefixShipment.get({ id: $stateParams.shipment_id } , function(data{
  $scope.booking = data.booking
});
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use Constructor !! try this:

```
$scope.shipment = Shipment($scope.shipment)
$scope.shipment.$save(function() {
  debugger
});
```